# How to kill an android application

Tags: android

I have tried the following code in my back button but it opens the beginning activity again.

```
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Comment: Which version of Android is that? killProcess used to kill the app.

Comment: Please post some more code.

Comment: This code is under the back button

Answer (score 1):

As per android guidelines, you **should not** kill the application. You have to use `finish()` in each activity lifecycle to safely return to your initial activity and then exit the application.

If you want to exit the app in `onBackPressed` event on your initial activity, just calling `finish()` will do the job.

If service, `stopSelf()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It will kill your application. All your services/receivers, Thread everything would be stopped.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
   System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Unless some new version of Android re-launches every application when the process dies. Unfortunately, AshyP have not mentioned the Android version, and whether it is a real device or the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot kill your application. The Android SDK does not allow this.

Comment: why the downvote? . if its wrong please specify reason as well as the solution .